# mapping NA to unknown using ifelse

Tags: r

I am using:

```
raw <- c('0', '13', 'NULL')

data <- data.frame(raw)
data$number <- as.numeric(as.character(data$raw))

data

data$category <- ifelse(data$number == 0, "0",
ifelse(data$number > 0 & data$number <= 7, "[1 ... 7]",
ifelse(data$number > 7 & data$number <= 14, "[8 ... 14]",
ifelse(data$number > 14 & data$number <= 31, "[15 ... 31]",
ifelse(data$number > 31 & data$number <= 62, "[32 ... 62]",
ifelse(data$number > 62, "63++",
ifelse(is.na(data$number) == TRUE, "unknown",
"unknown")))))))

data
```

One would think that the number == "NULL" entry is changed to "unknown" but I get:

```
   raw number   category
1    0      0          0
2   13     13 [8 ... 14]
3 NULL     NA       <NA>
```

instead of:

```
   raw number   category
1    0      0          0
2   13     13 [8 ... 14]
3 NULL     NA       unknown
```

Can someone please tell me why? A current workaround is to run:

```
data$category[which(is.na(data$number))] = "unknown"
```

after the block of code above.

Comment: Looks like you could use the `case_when()` function or the `cut()` function.

Comment: It's not really clear what your goal is. As it stands, your question seems more of a debugging question. What exactly do you want to do? Add more details to your question. not just code.

Comment: @NelsonGon - sorry but this is perfectly reproducible code with the IS and WANT ...

Comment: Alright then. Fair enough.

Comment: @RLave - I usually use dplyr and case statements for this. Unfortunately, the deployment environment does not like it. Could you please be so kind and provide cut code, which I tend to use to usually define quartiles ...

Comment: Another comment: `is.na(data$number) == TRUE` you can just remove the `== TRUE` part generally, since `is.na()` will give you already a bool. Also maybe use `is.null()` instead

Comment: @RLave yes I know. Thanks.I was not aware of the fact that there is an is.null(). Still puzzled why the catch all does not not map everything else to 'unknown' ....

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is the way you wanted this, but sure it has a lot less verbose code, by using the `cut()` function.

```
data$category <- cut(data$number, 
    breaks=c(-Inf, 0, 7, 14, 31, 62, Inf), # you decide the cuts
    labels = c("0", "[1..7]", "[8..14]", "[15 ... 31]", "[32 ... 62]", "63++")) 
    # labels for each category
```

Unfortunately you need these two lines to convert the `NA` to `"Unknown"`:

```
levels(data$category) <- c(levels(data$category), "Unknown")
data$category[is.na(data$number)] <- "Unknown"
data
#     raw number category
# 1    0      0        0
# 2   13     13  [8..14]
# 3 NULL     NA  Unknown
```

Data:

```
raw <- c('0', '13', 'NULL')

data <- data.frame(raw)
data$number <- as.numeric(as.character(data$raw))
```

---

Benchmarking:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  #cut
  cut = {data$category <- cut(data$number, 
                              breaks=c(-Inf, 0, 7, 14, 31, 62, Inf), 
                              labels = c("0", "[1..7]", "[8..14]", "[15 ... 31]", "[32 ... 62]", "63++"))
  levels(data$category) <- c(levels(data$category), "Unknown")
  data$category[is.na(data$number)] <- "Unknown"},
  #findInt
  findInt = {vec<-c(0,7,14,31,62)
  levels<-c(vec[1],sprintf("[%d ... %d]",(vec+1)[-length(vec)],vec[-1]),
            paste0(vec[length(vec)]+1,"++"))
  res<-levels[findInterval(data$number,vec,left.open=TRUE)+1]
  res[is.na(res)]<-"unknown"},
  # lapply
  lapply = {data$category <- lapply(data$number,function(x) {
    if(is.na(x) || is.null(x)) "unknown"
    else if(x == 0) "0"
    else if(x > 0 & x <= 7) "[1 ... 7]"
    else if(x > 7 & x <= 14) "[8 ... 14]"
    else if(x > 14 & x <= 31) "[15 ... 31]"
    else if(x > 31 & x <= 62) "[32 ... 62]"
    else if(x > 62) "63++"
    else "unknown"
  })},
  # ifelse
  ifelse = {data$category <- 
    ifelse(is.na(data$number), "unknown", 
           ifelse(data$number == 0, "0",
                  ifelse(data$number > 0 & data$number <= 7, "[1 ... 7]",
                         ifelse(data$number > 7 & data$number <= 14, "[8 ... 14]",
                                ifelse(data$number > 14 & data$number <= 31, "[15 ... 31]",
                                       ifelse(data$number > 31 & data$number <= 62, "[32 ... 62]",
                                              ifelse(data$number > 62, "63++", "???")))))))}
                               )
```

Gives:

```
# Unit: microseconds
#    expr     min       lq       mean   median       uq        max neval
#     cut 132.207 139.4185  154.78149 144.9770 154.5925    283.043   100
# findInt  18.329  21.7850   26.58004  26.2915  28.8460     60.996   100
#  lapply  14.122  15.6250 4269.73574  17.2770  18.7800 425198.055   100
#  ifelse  81.728  84.8835   96.09675  88.9400  96.3010    193.503   100
```

Comment: Wouldn't we want to use a realistically big dataset if doing benchmarking?

Comment: Results are more or less the same, findInterval is the fastest. If you want you can try it :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'd rather use conditional assignment with `within()`, which is clearer.

```
data <- within(data, {
  category <- NA
  category[number == 0] <- 0
  category[number > 0 & number <= 7] <- "[1 ... 7]"
  category[number > 7 & number <= 14] <- "[8 ... 14]"
  category[number > 14 & number <= 31] <- "[15 ... 31]"
  category[number > 31 & number <= 62] <- "[32 ... 62]"
  category[number > 62] <- "[32 ... 62]"
  category[is.na(number)] <- "unknown"
})

> data
   raw number   category
1    0      0          0
2   13     13 [8 ... 14]
3 NULL     NA    unknown
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this works for you to continue with your current approach: Renamed `data` to `df` because there's a function named `data`

```
df$category[is.na(df$category)]<-"Unknown"
df$category
```

Answer (score 1):

If you move `is.na()` to the beginning your current code will work:

```
data$category <- 
  ifelse(is.na(data$number), "unknown", 
    ifelse(data$number == 0, "0",
      ifelse(data$number > 0 & data$number <= 7, "[1 ... 7]",
        ifelse(data$number > 7 & data$number <= 14, "[8 ... 14]",
          ifelse(data$number > 14 & data$number <= 31, "[15 ... 31]",
            ifelse(data$number > 31 & data$number <= 62, "[32 ... 62]",
              ifelse(data$number > 62, "63++", "???")))))))

> data
   raw number   category
1    0      0          0
2   13     13 [8 ... 14]
3 NULL     NA    unknown
```

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote it to be a bit friendlier with an lapply instead of nested ifelse function calls.  The notable change is to test first for is.na() and to return "unknown" rather than as the default check at the end.  Reason being, when NA is passed into the function, your first test is if (NA==0 ) but this will return NA and neither TRUE nor FALSE and this is why it's NA and not completing its checks to return "unknown"

```
data$category <- lapply(data$number,function(x) {
  if(is.na(x) || is.null(x)) "unknown"
  else if(x == 0) "0"
  else if(x > 0 & x <= 7) "[1 ... 7]"
  else if(x > 7 & x <= 14) "[8 ... 14]"
  else if(x > 14 & x <= 31) "[15 ... 31]"
  else if(x > 31 & x <= 62) "[32 ... 62]"
  else if(x > 62) "63++"
  else "unknown"
})
```

Comment: Not very efficient.

Comment: why? ifelse() is itself generally not very efficient

Comment: I guess. But if only deals with a vector of length 1 and your anonymous function only deals with one number at a time. But probably an unfair criticism since it is still much better than original solution and works correctly.

Comment: I just timed it.  my solution is more efficient than yours ;) did a data <- data.frame(number=runif(10000000))

system.time(
data$category <- lapply(data$number,function(x) ( ... ))  and similarly for your solution above.     user  system elapsed 
  11.85    0.03   11.94  vs    user  system elapsed 
  12.29    0.87   13.31

Comment: It is not really my solution.. just modified the OP original solution so it would give output as expected. If you want a "fair" benchmark compare to `RLave` solution using `cut()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#define a vector with the range values
vec<-c(0,7,14,31,62)
#create your labels
levels<-c(vec[1],sprintf("[%d ... %d]",(vec+1)[-length(vec)],vec[-1]),
                paste0(vec[length(vec)]+1,"++"))
#use findInterval to create your result
res<-levels[findInterval(data$number,vec,left.open=TRUE)+1]
#substitute the NA's
res[is.na(res)]<-"unknown"
```